# While using <app-child> selector to bind with @Input it's template is visible in every other component

Tags: angular, input, angular-components

child.component

```
selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
            <div class="container">
            <div class="table">
              <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th> <th>Paswword</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody *ngFor="let info of loginInfo">
                <tr>
                  <td>{{info.name}}</td>
                  <td>{{info.password}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </div>
          </div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css'],
  // encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None // ** nome, shadowdom, native
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() loginInfo: { name: string, password: string };
```

app.component

```
 selector: 'app-root',
  template: ` <app-child [loginInfo]="loginDetails"></app-child> `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'lifecycle';
  loginDetails = [
    { name: 'qwe', password: '123' },
    { name: 'rty', password: 'pom@123' },
  ];
}
```

While binding the @Input() using the child selector tag the child component template is shown in every other component. Is there any way that it'll be shown in child component only?

Answer (score 0):

App component is shared between all components, so if in its template view you insert a component selector, all other components will see it;
If you want other components don't see child template you must 
don't insert it in app component template.

You have to create another component  where you have to put app-child selector and then call it  when app component is load.

**In app component-routing -module**

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: 'newComponent',
    loadChildren: () => import('app/newComponent/newComponent.module')
      .then(m => m.NewComponentModule),
  }
]
```

So when app component is load automatically new component is load

Comment: Thanks. But how can I bind the @Input variable from child to app component?

Comment: You have to create another component  where you have to put app-child selector and then call it  when app component is load.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another componet to bind @Input variable. like :

1) AppComponent = Paraent component.

2) create a componet  **(BillComponent)**  and then define template:

`<app-child [loginInfo]="loginDetails"></app-child>`, inside it

3) create a routing for BillComponent :

```
{path: 'generate-bill', component: BillComponent},
```

inside **app-routing.module.ts**

4) Now, billComponent.ts file look like this :

```
selector: 'app-bill',
  template: ` <app-child [loginInfo]="loginDetails"></app-child> `,
  styleUrls: ['./bill.component.css']
})
export class BillComponent {
  title = 'lifecycle';
  loginDetails = [
    { name: 'qwe', password: '123' },
    { name: 'rty', password: 'pom@123' },
  ];
}
```

5) child component will be same as you mention in your code.

**Note : Please check the flow of component.like parenet , sibling or child component.**